# In R, how do I make a plot for only one group?

Tags: r, plot

What I want to do is to apply the plot function only to certain selection of records in a dataset. Let's say, I have a column of length (numeric), a column of body mass (numeric) and a column of sex (M or F) (of some animal). I want to scatterplot the length vs the mass, but only for M, so that F won't appear on the plot. How do I do that?

Comment: say your data is a dataframe with sex as a character variable that takes the values "M" and "F". `plot(dataset[dataset$sex=="M",]$length, dataset[dataset$sex=="M",]$mass)` would achieve what you want. in general you should read about subsetting in R http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Subsetting.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple ways to subset a dataframe:

```
mydata <- data.frame(
length = rnorm(100 , 100 , 20),
mass   = rnorm(100 , 80,5),
sex    = sample( factor(c("male", "female") ) , 100 , replace=TRUE)
)

with( mydata[ mydata$sex=="male",  ] , plot(mass , length  ) )

# or

with( subset(mydata , sex=="male") , plot(mass, length ) )

# or make a new dataset

mydata2 <- mydata[  mydata$sex=="male" , ]

plot(mydata2$mass , mydata2$length)
```

In each case, `mydata$sex=="male"` makes a vector of `TRUE` and `FALSE` of length `nrow(mydata)` that is used to select the appropriate rows of the dataframe like this:

```
logical_vec_to_select <- mydata$sex=="male"
mydata[ logical_vec_to_select ,  ]
```

And the same technique can be used to subset columns of a dataframe or matrix.